# Логирование в Golang

Tags: golang, логирование

Всем привет

Пишу серверное приложение и мне потребовалось реализовать логирование. Немного погуглив, появились мысли, что какого-то единого подхода к логированию в Go нет.

Вопрос в следующем: ***Как организовать логирование в Go и в лог-файл, и на консоль?***

Знаю, что в разработке под андроид есть методы, вроде Log.d(). И вот хотелось бы что-то из этой серии, но под Go.

Comment: это? https://golang.org/pkg/log/ или просто https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf и пишите в файл

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719525/how-to-log-messages-to-the-console-and-a-file-both-in-golang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Логирование в файл:

```
l = log.New(file, "", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
l.Println()
```

На консоль:

```
l = log.New(os.Stdout,"",log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
```

Comment: Поправте ваше сообшение кнопкой "правка", чтобы его можно было прочесть.

Comment: а как уровень указать?